How to access the environment in github actions?
I have been trying the following, assuming it would work, but it doesn't (the echo is empty). Is there an option to access the environment setting? Would be nicer rather than creating an additional ENVIRONMENT variable.
  deploy-staging:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build-test-push]
    concurrency: staging
    environment: staging
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Environment
        run: |
          echo "${{ github.environment }}"


Based on this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/accessing-contextual-information-about-workflow-runs I think the information is not available in any of the existing contexts. So creating and additional variable is probably your best choice still.
